# center coordinate of widget in pyside qtwidget

Tags: python, pyside, qtwidgets

I am trying to find the center coordinates of a widget, but `self.height` and `self.width` are not the widget sizes, because setting the center to the half of these draws outside of the visible area. How could I set `x` and `y` to the center of the widget?

```
class Chooser(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        x = self.width()/2
        y = self.height()/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre of the widget relative to what?

Relative to itself:

```
c = widget.rect().center()
print(c)
```

Relative to its parent:

```
print(widget.mapToParent(c))
```

Relative to the screen:

```
print(widget.mapToGlobal(c))
```

NB: the last two will be the same if the widget has no parent. And see the [Window Geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) overview in the Qt Docs for some other important metrics that may be relevant.

Comment: I have the widget in a `QtGui.QGridLayout()` and I manually found the center to be somewhere at `(155,155)` but `self.rect().center()` gives me `PySide.QtCore.QPoint(319, 239)`, so using it as center places most of the element out of view :( It seems like somehow the widget thinks it is bigger than it actually is.

Comment: is it possible that the widget gets resized when I put it in the layout, but I ask for the center during init?

Comment: @fbence. Sure - but why not just test your code to see what actually happens?

Comment: I wasn't in the situation to do it, but it was an unnecessary more of a rhetorical question, I give you that :) Anyway, of course that was the problem... I set the coordinates in the `__init__`, while the widget got resized after, when being added to the layout.